# How to call a function with arguments in other functions with additional arguments?

Tags: python, function

I'm working on a problem and want to plot multiple functions that include other functions:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

r_x = 14e-2
l_m = np.arange(2e-5, 4e-5, 1e-6)

def first(l_m, r_x):
    first = 1.03 * (l_m/r_x) 
    return first

plt.pyplot.figure()
plt.pyplot.plot(l_m, first(l_m, r_x))
plt.pyplot.xlabel("l_m")
plt.pyplot.ylabel("first")
plt.pyplot.show()
```

and this works properly, but once I try including my first() in another function like so:

```
def second(a_x, first):
    second = 0.5*((a_x**2)/(0.25*(np.pi)*(first**2)))
    return second

plt.pyplot.figure()
plt.pyplot.plot(l_m, second(a_x, first(l_m, r_x)))
plt.pyplot.xlabel("l_m")
plt.pyplot.ylabel("second")
plt.pyplot.show()
```

It could very well be that I forgot to copy a part or changed my code too much while choosing which part to ask about. I did find a solution but it's a very clumsy one in which I don't refer to the functions but rather their definitions and thus have absolutely impossible and stupidly looking functions.

How do I find an elegant solution to my problem?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? I think you forgot to describe it

Comment: What happens when you run your second code? Why not run first() and store it in a variable and then pass that to second()?

Comment: I.. ran the here written code and it spat out what I needed?

Comment: The problems that I had while coding the first time were related to the fact that one can't square a function or so it said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def second(a_x, first):
    second = 0.5*((a_x**2)/(0.25*(np.pi)*(first**2)))
    return second

plt.pyplot.figure()
plt.pyplot.plot(l_m, second(a_x, first(l_m, r_x)))
```

In this case you aren't really passing the function as an argument. You're just passing the value returned by the function first() and then squaring it. That's why it works. And if you want to do this then you should rename `first` as an argument in `second` so you know it's not the function you're referring to.

If for whatever reason you do want to pass the function and call it within second, you can try

```
def second(a_x, first, l_m, r_x):
    second = 0.5*((a_x**2)/(0.25*(np.pi)*(first(l_m, r_x)**2)))
    return second

plt.pyplot.figure()
plt.pyplot.plot(l_m, second(a_x, first, l_m, r_x))
```

The difference here is that `first()` is actually being called inside `second` instead of being called outside and sending it's value

Comment: Ah! This worked. The second part helped me! Thank you so much, I've been working on this for way too long.